# Exception Recasting Error message in Java

Tags: java, exception, jvm, try-catch

According to [this article](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/exceptions/exceptions_recasting.shtml) , new Exception object can be thrown from catch block without specifying "throws" or without enclosing this throw in another try/catch block.

But when i try to do following in Eclipse Juno:

```
public class Try {

class Trial extends Exception{}

public static void main(String s[]){
    try{
    }catch(Exception e){
            throw  new Trial();
    }
}
```

}

It shows error messages and ask me to add throw or another try/catch around "throw  new Trial();". Is it JVM dependent or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are throwing a checked exception, compiler just complains because your method signature says otherwise

```
public static void main(String s[]) throws Trial
```

should fix it, if you plan to throw it from main.

Answer (score 5):

The same article says

> This is an unchecked exception: we don't need to declare that we throw
>   it, and the caller doesn't need to explicitly handle it. If such an
>   exception occurs, it will be "mopped up" by the uncaught

So the exception is unchecked which extends `RuntimeException`